# How to enable keyboard selections in a MUI Select component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I would like to use a MUI Select component with the keyboard by tabbing into it, then pressing the first letter of the option I want to select, which should then auto-select the first item in the list that starts with that letter, without ever actually opening the select list. Subsequent key presses of the same letter should cycle through the remaining options that start with that letter. Pressing a different key should then start the process over, choosing the first item in the list that begins with that letter.

I have not yet found a property in the API for how to enable this behavior, nor any examples for it. Note, I did see this behavior in the documentation [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-select/#native-select) for the 'Native Select' example, but I'd like to use the normal version of the Select component.

Below is the code I have so far along with a link to a Code Sandbox for it.

```js
import * as React from "react";
import {
  FormControl,
  InputLabel,
  Select,
  SelectChangeEvent,
  MenuItem,
  Box
} from "@mui/material";

export default function App() {
  const [partOfSpeech, setPartOfSpeech] = React.useState("");

  const handleChange = (event: SelectChangeEvent) => {
    setPartOfSpeech(event.target.value as string);
  };

  return (
    <Box sx={{ maxWidth: 200 }}>
      <FormControl fullWidth>
        <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Part of Speech</InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
          id="demo-simple-select"
          value={partOfSpeech}
          label="Part of Speech"
          onChange={handleChange}
        >
          <MenuItem value="">none</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="adjective">adjective</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="noun">noun</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="adverb">adverb</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="verb">verb</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-select-with-keypress-go9vvf)

I consulted the following MUI references but could not find any information for how to achieve this behavior:

- [Select](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-select/)
- [Select API](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/select/)

Answer (score 0):

use `NativeSelect` instead of `Select`